# Rendering issue related to div tags containing datatable

Tags: php, jquery, html, datatable, render

This is my first post on some Q&A site. Point out my tiniest mistakes and correct me. I've started learning PHP and I am using WAMP server. I am having multiple rendering issues. I will present one first. I have an index.php page on which I want to display five tables namely Branch, Student, Subject, Exam and Marks. Now I have kept display buttons for each tables mentioned above on the same page. I don't want the page to get refreshed so the input type for the button is "button" not "submit". And then I want to check if the button is clicked or not so I am using isset($_POST['button']) where button is the name of display button for respective table. And if the button is clicked then I am displaying the datatable for that particular table only while other tables are hidden.

Rendering issue of one table at a time : I want that when I click on Display Branch Table button the Branch table will be displayed and after that if I click on Display Student Table button then Student table should be displayed and the rest of tables should be hidden and likewise for all the tables. Now the below code has the jquery which is too much redundant and I want to optimize it. Also I've a part of my PHP code which displays branch table whose div tag id is branch1 and for student it is student1 and likewise. On clicking the display branch button I cannot see anything happening. It means the if(isset($_POST['display_branch'])) is not working on button click. Also there is a div tag for each table and has different id but same class(i.e. render)
I would like to know where I am wrong here and I don't want the page to be reloaded again.

jQuery:

```
$('.render').hide();
$('#display_branch').click(function (event) {
    $('#student1').hide();
    $('#subject1').hide();
    $('#exam1').hide();
    $('#marks1').hide();
    $('#branch1').show();
});

$('#display_student').click(function (event) {
    $('#subject1').hide();
    $('#exam1').hide();
    $('#marks1').hide();
    $('#branch1').hide();
    $('#student1').show();
});
$('#display_subject').click(function (event) {
    $('#subject1').show();
    $('#exam1').hide();
    $('#marks1').hide();
    $('#branch1').hide();
    $('#student1').hide();
});
$('#display_exam').click(function (event) {
    $('#subject1').hide();
    $('#exam1').show();
    $('#marks1').hide();
    $('#branch1').hide();
    $('#student1').hide();
});
$('#display_marks').click(function (event) {
    $('#subject1').hide();
    $('#exam1').hide();
    $('#marks1').show();
    $('#branch1').hide();
    $('#student1').hide();
});
```

Display buttons:

```
       <div id="display" style="position:absolute; top:100px;">
       <form action="" method="post">
       <input type="button" id="display_branch" name="display_branch" value="Display Branch Table" >
       <input type="button" id="display_student" name="display_student" value="Display Student Table">
       <input type="button" id="display_subject" name="display_subject" value="Display Subject Table">
       <input type="button" id="display_exam" name="display_exam" value="Display Exam Table">
       <input type="button" id="display_marks" name="display_marks" value="Display Marks Table">
       </form>
       </div>
```

PHP Code Fragment:

```
   if(isset($_POST['display_branch']))
   {
   $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM branch");?>
 <div class="render" id="branch1" style="position:absolute; left:200px; top:150px;">
        <table id="datatables" class="display">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Branch ID</th>
                    <th>Branch Name</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                $branch_id= $row['branch_id'];
                $branch_name = $row['branch_name'];?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $branch_id;?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $branch_name;?></td>                         
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                }
                ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>}
```

I searched a lot and tried many ways but not getting it perfectly. Hope this discussion will help some others to solve similar issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$_POST['display_branch']
```

This requires **POST request** with display_branch param given.

You got basically two options to hide/show elements like this.

- 1 have them all hidden at the load time and then just selectively show like this http://jsfiddle.net/DVd3A/1/
- 2 do an ajax request on button click with `$.ajax()` like this http://jsfiddle.net/sLXMU/3/

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I'll try to implement the above suggestions and get back to you.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Regarding the second approach, how can achieve the same using ajax ?

Comment: You can have a separate page which will contain your PHP code as shown in original question. f.e. if ($_POST['display_branch']) { die('My desired content'); } and then you request the page with $.ajax() like this $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { display_branch: "1" }
}).done(function( data ) {
  $('#display_area').html(data);
});

Comment: So I've to use the display buttons mentioned in my question instead of the links you mentioned in the solution ?
If yes, the input type for each button should be submit or else post request will not be generated. Is that correct ?
And I am not getting the gist of data parameter of the ajax function. What is display_area in it and that "1" after display_branch ?

Comment: you can trigger the `$.ajax()` function with any element (link or button). Just make sure, that you pass the POST data in **data** parameter of `$.ajax()` function. The 1 there is optional, its just some value to assign. This could also be true or any other.

Comment: What about display_area ?
Is it the id to be defined in the separate php file ?

Comment: its customized to your needs (the data variable is changed to a query string because that way we can make POST parameter variable). And the display area is just a place where your content is loaded afterwards.

Comment: Okay I think this will help me out. Thanks again !!

Answer (score 0):

This is not the complete solution to your problem, but this is some optimization of your jQuery code. I have created dummy scenario of your problem. You can take some help from this code:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="tables">
    <table id="branch1">
    </table>
    <table id="subject1">
    </table>
    <table id="student1">
    </table>
    <table id="marks1">
    </table>
    <table id="exam1">
    </table>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('#display_branch').click(function (event) {
    var table = $(this).attr(id).split("_");
    $("#tables").find("table").hide();
    $("#"+table[1]+"1").show();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. This will clash with my 2nd rendering issue which I'll post after this is solved. Actually I've used a jQuery plugin for displaying tables in datatables format. To keep that formatting to persist I've to keep table id attribute as 'datatables' and table class attribute as 'display' or else regular table is displayed.